# Jacoco jmx dump, Connection reset error

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, jacoco

I am running tomcat with a jacoco agent like this:

```
-javaagent:/path_to_jar/jacocoagent.jar=jmx=true,output=tcpclient,port=8001
```

which I know is working because lsof command lists `88208 TCP localhost:**8001** (LISTEN)`.

When I run this example [code](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/org.jacoco.examples/src/org/jacoco/examples/ExecutionDataClient.java) with `PORT = 8001;` I get the error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

This appears to be an older example from jacoco.  Has something changed with that way I need to access the tcp server?  I have also tried to access jacoco through their [MBeanClient](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/org.jacoco.examples/src/org/jacoco/examples/MBeanClient.java), but it gives me an InstanceNotFoundException and appears that tomcat does not have "org.jacoco:type=Runtime" listed as a bean when I print out all of the domains.

Any suggestions for either option?  I just need to be able to get a dump file without stopping the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed some more java arguments when starting my server:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999"
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

Without these JMX could not see jacoco as a bean on my localhost.

(this also works for glassfish, but they need to be set using `<jvm-options>`)