# Jacoco agent - empty exec file for spring boot app

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, jacoco

I am trying to gather code coverage of my springboot app when it was run in a docker container.  In the docker container, it is running as follows.

```
java -javaagent:jacocoagent.jar=destfile=integrationTest.exec -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar myApp.jar
```

Then I run some tests that connect to the web service running in the springboot app.  Once the test is done, the integrationTest.exec exists but is empty.  I there an extra step I need to take?  When the docker container is stopped, is the dump created?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Jacoco agent will take a dump when application exits.(it has to be stopped gracefully). if you just kill the process it might not take a dump. There is the alternate way you can take a dump before you stop or terminate your container. You can open JMX connection and then remotely execute dump on the process.

For more details take a look at below links:
http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html
[Jacoco jmx dump, Connection reset error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776124/jacoco-jmx-dump-connection-reset-error)
https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/org.jacoco.examples/src/org/jacoco/examples/MBeanClient.java